# Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState when opening pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I ran into a new error today when opening Spark the way I always do. I've never seen the error, but now it is preventing me from running my python scripts.

I have pyspark aliased in my .bash_profile and when I open pyspark from my terminal I get this error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

I found this post: [Apache Spark with Python: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059445/apache-spark-with-python-error)

which seemed to be what I needed so I went down the line and tried using sudo and I made sure the mentioned jar file was in place, but I am still receiving the error.

Here are the relevant lines in my .bashrc:

```
 export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

alias sudo='sudo '
alias pyspark="/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir='file:///tmp/spark-warehouse' \
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 \
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34 \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 \
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:2.0.0"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you need aliased? pyspark should just be on PATH. Which spark & scala version?

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not need an alias, but the same happens when I go through my directory in the terminal and try to start pyspark from there. My spark version is 2.1. and java version check output the following: openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)