# sc is not defined in SparkContext

Tags: linux, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

My Spark package is spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.

I exported spark variables as

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/harry/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I opened spark notebook by

```
pyspark
```

I am able to load packages from spark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
print(SQLContext)
```

output is

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.context.SQLContext'>
```

But my error is

```
print(sc)
"sc is undefined"
```

plz can anyone help me out ...!

Comment: Did you create instance of spark context? you need to create spark context.

Comment: I havent any.I am very new to spark,Please can you tell me in clear  of how to do it...! 
   
   ** sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) **.

I did this .but still i got same error , sc is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *pysparkShell*, `SparkContext` is already initialized as `SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*])` so you just need to use `getOrCreate()` to set the `SparkContext` to a variable as

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

For coding purpose in simple *local mode*, you can do the following

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
print(sc)
print(sqlContext)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply..But i got this error ****Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at /home/harry/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:186 
****

Comment: Thank you ..!It worked fine..!
Now can i use this sc directly to load a csv file..?

Comment: great to hear that @HarishBodduna :)

Comment: got another issue..!

Comment: While loading csv file , getting this error..!

    data = 
     spark.read.format("csv").load("/home/harry/Music/classification3.csv")

Error:name 'spark' is not defined

Comment: I commented above sir , the error says spark is not defined..!

    spark.read.format("csv").load("/home/harry/Music/Classification.csv")

Comment: why did you use spark there ? use sqlContext after you create the variable as i have mentioned in the answer instead of spark and you should be fine

Comment: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"

Comment: This is the error while writing the above code which u mentioned sir..!
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

Error: IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"

Comment: sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() *******sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) ********Error: IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder'

Comment: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder'

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059445/apache-spark-with-python-error

Comment: Thank you soo much sir for help..But when i load the link FILE NOT FOUND page is being loaded..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165031/discussion-between-harish-bodduna-and-ramesh-maharjan).