# Cannot access pyspark in EMR cluster jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I've created a spark cluster on EMR.
But I'm unable to access pyspark when I open it with a notebook.

**Configuration:**

[image]

**Example:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

[image]

I also cannot access `sc` which I was under the impression would be available.

```
sc.list_packages()
```

> NameError: name 'sc' is not defined

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here but I'm completely new to EMR and have spent a bunch of time on this already.

Are there any ideas I should try to debug this?

Comment: I can't see your images, but I think this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762187/5858851 (not voting to close unless you agree since my python badge would be binding)

Answer (score 1):

When I opened my notebook with "JupyterLab" instead of "Jupyter" all libraries were available.

[image]

Comment: Why it should make a difference?